# Rails controller sending js response before saving model

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Rails controller that updates a model via POST and sends a js response to update the view accordingly.

However, the response is sent before the model is saved and is not properly shown.

My controller:

```
def reload_regional_groups_ajax

  @shown_regional_groups = RegionalGroup.limit(4)
  @map_data = RegionalGroup.all.to_gmaps4rails

  if params[:exec] == "join"
    if current_user.can_join_new_group?
      @regional_group_membership = RegionalGroupMembership.new({:user_id => current_user.id, :regional_group_id => params[:reg_id]})
      @regional_group_membership.save
    else
      raise t("view.regional_group.membership.create.limit")
    end

  elsif params[:exec] == "remove"
    @regional_group_membership = RegionalGroupMembership.where("user_id = ? and regional_group_id = ?", current_user.id, params[:reg_id])
    RegionalGroupMembership.destroy(@regional_group_membership) 
  elsif params[:search]
    @shown_regional_groups = RegionalGroup.where("name LIKE ? OR post_code LIKE ?", '%'+params[:search]+'%', params[:search]+'%')
    @map_data = @shown_regional_groups.to_gmaps4rails  
  end

  @regional_groups_user = current_user.regional_groups

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

The js file only reloads some partials.

I have also tried to put if @model.save before the "respond_to" block, but the result is the same.

I have logged the response and only with the "search" option of my code the view is updated, because it doesn't update anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems all the problems were in the **`current_user`** variable, which is the one containing the logged in user (set by Devise). It is affected by caching.

The solution is adding this in the controller:

```
@user = User.find(current_user.id)
```

And removing any reference to `current_user` in the controller and in the views.